# html and javascript game function not changing global variable

Tags: javascript, html, adventure

When X,Y, and Z are equal to 3 then locationName should be equal to Sol, but this is not the case. I believe the problem is with my variable name not being updated but it could be something else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jordan's Space Explorer </title>

</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="goNorth()">Go North</button>
  <button onclick="goSouth()">Go South</button>
  <button onclick="goEast()">Go East</button>
  <button onclick="goWest()">Go West</button>
  <button onclick="goUp()">Go Up</button>
  <button onclick="goDown()">Go Down</button>
  <button onclick="locationQuery()">Where am I?</button>
  <button onClick="quit"()>Quit</button>

</body>

<script> 

// Confirm user wants to play.
confirm("Do you want to play Jordan's Space Explorer?");

alert("The game is working.");

// Declare start location.
var locationY = 0;
var locationX = 0;
var locationZ = 0; 
var locationName = "in Space";


//Go directions
function goNorth(){
    locationY ++;
    console.log("You head North.");
}

function goSouth(){
    locationY --;
    console.log("You head South.");
}

function goEast(){
    locationX ++;
    console.log("You head East");
}   

function goWest(){
    locationX --;
    console.log("You head West");
}

function goUp(){
    locationZ ++;
    console.log("You go up.");
}

function goDown(){
    locationZ --;
    console.log("You go down.");
}
function locationQuery(){
    console.log("X" +locationX);
    console.log("Y" +locationY);
    console.log("Z" +locationZ);
    console.log("You are " +locationName);
}

// Encounters
if(locationX === 3 && locationY === 3 && locationZ === 3){
 locationName = "Sol";
 alert("Arrived at " + locationName);
}
if(locationX===0  && locationY===0  && locationZ===0){
    alert("It worked.");
}    




</script>

</html>
```

I am new to programming and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should also change the confirm line to `if (confirm("Do you want to play Jordan's Space Explorer?") == false) {return false;}` otherwise the script will continue to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you execute your `// Encounters part` only once, at initialization. You should put it in a function :

```
function encounters(){
 if(locationX === 3 && locationY === 3 && locationZ === 3){
  locationName = "Sol";
  alert("Arrived at " + locationName);
 }
 if(locationX===0  && locationY===0  && locationZ===0){
    alert("It worked.");
 }    
}
```

and call that function every time you change the position :

```
function goDown(){
    locationZ --;
    console.log("You go down.");
    encounters();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  with,

```
function locationQuery(){
    console.log("X" +locationX);
    console.log("Y" +locationY);
    console.log("Z" +locationZ);
   // Encounters
 if(locationX === 3 && locationY === 3 && locationZ === 3){
  locationName = "Sol";
  alert("Arrived at " + locationName);
 }
  if(locationX===0  && locationY===0  && locationZ===0){
    alert("It worked.");
  }   
    console.log("You are " +locationName);
```

}

Update `locationName` against given condition by invoking `locationQuery()` function